# A service calling a service, onServiceConnected never called?

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have a remote service, it calls some jni to start a c process. After it starts the process it can report the port numbers for a remote activity (via AIDL) to connect to. I have a service in another .apk that starts the remote service, then binds to it. If the remote service is started **before** the Activity's service tries to connect to it, it will call onServiceConnected in the Activity's service. If the remote Activity is responsible for **both** starting and binding, the bind happens first, followed shortly by the onStartCommand(), but in this scenario onServiceConnected() is never called.

In my activity it is agnostic to the order of events **as long as** onServiceConnected() is eventually called. Why does this happen?

`______________________________________________`
To clarify, Remote service started first (the good scenario):
`______________________________________________`

V/rmt_service(11202): onStartCommand enter
V/rmt_service(11202): onStartCommand exit
V/rmt_service(11202): onBind enter
V/rmt_service(11202): Port:50336
V/rmt_service(11202): Port:50943
V/rmt_service(11202): Port:57703
V/rmt_service(11202): onBind exit

V/act_service(11221): onStartCommand - enter
V/act_service(11221): bindService - enter
V/act_service(11221): bindService - exit
V/act_service(11221): onStartCommand - exit

V/rmt_service(11202): onStartCommand enter
V/rmt_service(11202): onStartCommand exit

**V/act_service(11221): onServiceConnected - enter**
**V/act_service(11221): onServiceConnected - exit**
V/act_service(11251): onStartCommand - enter
V/act_service(11251): bindService - enter
V/act_service(11251): bindService - exit
V/act_service(11251): onStartCommand - exit

V/rmt_service(11202): onStartCommand enter
V/rmt_service(11202): onStartCommand exit

V/act_service(11251): onBind - enter
V/act_service(11251): onBind - exit
V/act_service(11251): onServiceConnected - enter
V/act_service(11251): onServiceConnected - exit

`______________________________________________`
Now the bad:
`______________________________________________`

V/act_service(11278): onStartCommand - enter
V/act_service(11278): bindService - enter
V/act_service(11278): bindService - exit
V/act_service(11278): onStartCommand - exit
V/act_service(11278): onBind - enter
V/act_service(11278): onBind - exit

V/rmt_service(11285): onBind enter

V/act_service(11278): getLib - enter

V/rmt_service(11285): Port:58782
V/rmt_service(11285): Port:41039
V/rmt_service(11285): Port:33770
V/rmt_service(11285): onBind exit
V/rmt_service(11285): onStartCommand enter
V/rmt_service(11285): onStartCommand exit

You can see that, even though I called startService() on the remote service before calling bindService() they system binds to the service first, and then calls onStartCommand().

Any help would be appreciated.

**edit**

Even if I add a pause after I call startService() it doesn't work, nor does bindService(intent, servConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); instead of starting then binding. It has to be previously running, then it connects fine, what gives?

Comment: Found the problem:
I was blocking on my event thread. So though the service was connected the OS was waiting for me to complete my task before it could notify me of it's completion. If you are having the same problem I can get more specific, just post up.

It won't let me answer for another 7 hours so I'll adjust accordingly then.

Comment: Hi there, I have a similar problem and haven't found a way out for a day, really frustrated. If your problem is solved could you have a look at my code here: http://ideone.com/cV5BJa? Basically the onServiceConnected never gets called...

Comment: You need to look at the Android documentation. It's an async callback, it won't happen as soon as you request bindService(). It'll happen some time in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It turns out that I haven't declare my service in the manifest. =(